# displaying and storing Arabic characters

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, unicode, nsarray, arabic

I have an array that stores it's elements from a text file. I want to store Arabic characters inside that file but i have problems:

1. When I try to write this word in text it display it opposite not correct :
   ex. شجرة I want to store that word
   when i paste it in text file it converted into backward direction like 
   tree becomes eert.
2. I don't know anything about Unicode converting to display it in a label??
   can any one help me with storing it in array and display it in label???

Thank you.

Comment: Your text editor probably isn't handling right-to-left scripts properly. I'm not sure what else you're asking.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 1):

The new release of Mac OS X 'Lion' is going to provide support for the arabic language system wide. I assume this will fix the problem of editing Arabic characters in Xcode. There is also a support for Arabic with text-to-voice services, a new Arabic 'speaker' or sound called Majed.